# If statement always true with enum in comparison

Tags: c#, if-statement, enums

I'm having a problem. I'm making a utility to do procedural generated maps.
I have a room pool and each rooms are disposed in a table of room. I have a method to connect all the room together which walk in the table and connect adjacent rooms.

I have an `enum` which contains the type of rooms :

```
public enum RoomType
{
    Default = 0,
    Building,
    Boss,
    Item,
    Standard,
    Start,
}
```

In the connection method I check the neighborhood to see what kind of room it is :

```
if (neighbourhood[2, 1] != null)
{
    if (firstLevel.isOn)
    {                     
        if (neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom == RoomType.Start)
        {
            roomGrid[x, y].AddConnection(neighbourhood[2, 1], Location.RIGHT)
        }
    }
    else if (neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom != RoomType.Boss)
        roomGrid[x, y].AddConnection(neighbourhood[2, 1], Location.RIGHT);
}
```

But when i check if the type of room is `Start`, it's always `true` and the connection is added.

[image: img]
[image: img2]

I don't know why this happens.

where i set the TypeOfRoom : 
[img3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibHlA.png)

Comment: Have you tried debugging?  Look what the values are set to and see if the code goes where you expect it.

Comment: The only explanation for this is that something changed the `TypeOfRoom` *after* the comparison.

Comment: How `TypeOfRoom` looks like? Is it a property? Do you have more than one thread accessing `neighbourhood` ?

Comment: Yep, i tried to debug (see the screens) 
TypeOfRoom is a argument of the room object and it is of RoomType

Comment: Is there an overload for `operator==` ?

Comment: And i have no overload for the operator==

Comment: Can you post the code where you're setting the `RoomType`?

Comment: Have you compiled with Debug configuration?

Comment: There is not enough code to provide usefull answers

Comment: @Sinatr both screenshots are on `neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom == RoomType.Start` so they match the shown code

Comment: @codroipo : not that i'm aware of

Comment: Just curious as to why your "Default" enum has an integer value of 0, but none of the other enums have an integer value. Do you have a reason for that?

Comment: @Donald.Record: nope no reason. I took over somebody else code and it was already there. It's working for all other checks (like for the boss room). Just not for the start

Comment: Does `AddConnection` (accidentially) modifies the type?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: no, the method does not modify the type.

Comment: @soupola: What visual studio version are you using? Do you use break points? Maybe you have a breakpoint with a condition that modifies the value, so it uses `neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom = RoomType.Start` instead of `neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom == RoomType.Start`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I use the 2015 version provided with unity and there are no others breakpoints

Comment: Are you sure the connection is made?  The two images shown should not mean that the AddConnection line is executed.  Hovering over `TypeofRoom` shows `RoomType.Standard`, so the condition should not be executed.  Hovering over `RoomType.Start` will always yield the value `Start`, but that does not mean the condition is met; it just means that `Start` == `Start`

Comment: @RicGaudet: the connection is made. When looking at the room in question, the connection is in the table of connection.

Comment: Kindly show us the get method for `TypeOfRoom`. Maybe something fishy happens there and since thats the only thing that is executed in your statement, thats what my money is on

Comment: you need to post more code. Show us your `Room` class and specifically your `TypeOfRoom` getter and setter (I'm assuming it is a property).

Comment: @InBetween: the room class is over 1000 lines... And the getter/setter are very basics  like :
    public RoomType TypeOfRoom { get; set; }

Comment: al right here's a really silly solution but i always give it a shot when something really doesn't make sense. Do me a favour and restart Visual Studio. sometimes the Debugger is just being silly. then try ytepping through the Statement and looking at the values again.

Comment: @GuyMontag: That's the first thing that i do when vs is not making sense ( I prefert to beleve it's the computer, not me :D). 
This time I have rebooted the computer to be sure. Still doing it

Comment: if that does not help, we need to further norrow the Problem down. Add `neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom = RoomType.Standard;` just before `if (neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom == RoomType.Start)`. if the condition is still met we can be sure that the Problem lies within checking the condition

Comment: @GuyMontag: Even when I assign the TypeOfRoom just before the condition (like you said) it's still passing in the condition. 
I feel like my whole life is a lie.

Comment: Your issue is most likely due to a race condition. Something is changing the values on another thread. Implement some logging logic in your `TypeOfRoom` setter, identifying the current thread . You'll probably find some unexpected results; more than one thread is messing with your `room`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is most likely due to a race condition. You can easily check if this is the case as follows:

```
if (neighbourhood[2, 1] != null)
{
    if (firstLevel.isOn)
    {
        var typeOfRoom = neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom; //store type in a local variable

        if (typeOfRoom == RoomType.Start) //check against local copy
        {
             roomGrid[x, y].AddConnection(neighbourhood[2, 1], Location.RIGHT)
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You will see now that the `if` condition works perfectly fine but `neighbourhood[2,1].TypeOfRoom` will not equal `typeOfRoom` which means it is being modified in another thread.

If you are not aware of how or where your objects are bieng modified by other threads then you have bigger issues to resolve as you don't seem to understand the code or the framework you are using.

If or when you *do* understand why and when this is happening you will need to implement some synchronization mechanism or steer (preferable) towards immutable implementations.

Answer (score 3):

What you're showing in your screenshot and what you're describing sounds impossible. When that happens, it's often because the application is multithreaded. It's impossible on one thread. But while it's executing another thread is modifying the values.

At the same time you might also be unintentionally passing around references to the same object to multiple functions.

But definitely check for anything involving threads, tasks, or parallel function calls. Or if this is running in a web environment, see if multiple requests could be accessing shared data.

Comment: Since this is a Unity project, I imagine there are a lot of ways multithreading could happen.